# rel_heights in plot_grid not responding

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I have two `ggplot`s I'm trying to put together using `cowplot`'s `plot_grid`:

First `data.frame` and `ggplot`:

```
require(ggplot2)
main.df <- data.frame(sample=c(paste("E.plus.A.plus",1:3,sep="_"),paste("E.minus.A.plus",1:3,sep="_"),paste("E.plus.A.minus",1:3,sep="_"),paste("E.minus.A.minus",1:3,sep="_")),
                      replicate=rep(1:3,4),cpm=c(rnorm(12)),
                      factor.level=factor(c(rep("E.plus.A.plus",3),rep("E.minus.A.plus",3),rep("E.plus.A.minus",3),rep("E.minus.A.minus",3)),
                                          levels=c("E.plus.A.plus","E.minus.A.plus","E.plus.A.minus","E.minus.A.minus")))

main.plot <- ggplot(main.df,aes(x=replicate,y=cpm,color=factor.level))+geom_point(size=3)+
  facet_wrap(~factor.level,ncol=length(levels(main.df$factor.level)))+
  labs(x="replicate",y="cpm")+scale_x_continuous(breaks=unique(main.df$replicate))+theme_bw()+
theme(legend.position="none",panel.border=element_blank(),strip.background=element_blank(),axis.title=element_text(size=8),plot.title=element_text(size=9,hjust=0.5))
```

Second `data.frame` and `ggplot`:

```
effects.df <- data.frame(factor.level=c("E.plus.A.plus-E.minus.A.plus","E.plus.A.plus-E.plus.A.minus","E.plus.A.plus-E.minus.A.minus",
                                        "E.minus.A.plus-E.plus.A.minus","E.minus.A.plus-E.minus.A.minus","E.plus.A.minus-E.minus.A.minus"),
                         effect=rnorm(6),effect.df=runif(6,0,0.5),p.value=runif(6,0,1),y=1:6+0.2)
effects.df$effect.high <- effects.df$effect+effects.df$effect.df
effects.df$effect.low <- effects.df$effect-effects.df$effect.df
effects.df$factor.level <- factor(effects.df$factor.level,levels=effects.df$factor.level)

sub.plot <- ggplot(effects.df,aes(x=effect,y=factor.level,color=factor.level))+geom_point(size=2.5,shape=19)+geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax=effect.high,xmin=effect.low),height=0.1)+
  geom_vline(xintercept=0,linetype="longdash",colour="black",size=0.25)+theme_bw()+theme(legend.position="none",panel.border=element_blank(),strip.background=element_blank(),axis.title=element_text(size=7),axis.text=element_text(size=7),legend.text=element_text(size=7),legend.title=element_text(size=7))+
  geom_text(aes(x=effects.df$effect,y=effects.df$y,label=format(signif(effects.df$p.value,2),scientific=T)),size=2.5)
```

My `plot_grid` command is:

```
require(cowplot)
plot_grid(main.plot,sub.plot,ncol=2,nrow=1,rel_widths=c(2,1.75),rel_heights=c(1,0.5))
```

as I want `sub.plot` to be half the height of `main.plot` and bottom aligned. This is what I'm getting though:

[image]

Playing around with `rel_heights` doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 3):

`rel_heights` allocates vertical space when you have two or more plots stacked one on top of the other. Since you have only one row of plots here, `rel_heights` doesn't do anything. For example, run `plot_grid(main.plot, sub.plot, rel_heights=c(2,1), ncol=1)` to see how `rel_heights` works.

To get the layout you want, you can stack an empty grob (graphics object) on top of the right-hand plot, which will result in the right-hand plot taking up half the vertical space available. In the code below, we use `arrangeGrob` from the `gridExtra` package to stack a `nullGrob()` on top of `sub.plot`. Then we place the output of `arrangeGrob` next to `main.plot`. By default, the two grobs `arrangeGrob` will each take up half the vertical space. However, if you decided, for example, that you want `sub.plot` to take up 2/3 of the vertical space, you would do `arrangeGrob(nullGrob(), sub.plot, ncol=1, heights=c(1,2))`.

```
require(cowplot)
require(gridExtra)
require(grid)

plot_grid(main.plot, arrangeGrob(nullGrob(), sub.plot, ncol=1), 
          ncol=2, rel_widths=c(2,1.75))
```

[image]

Comment: as gridExtra is being used maybe grid.arrange offers an alt approach `grid.arrange(main.plot, sub.plot, layout_matrix=matrix(c(1,1, NA, 2), 2))`